# Doesn't the rollback of a revision require sufficient reputation?

Tags: support, privileges, rollbacks

I rollbacked a revision, and created a new revision, but in the process, I didn't find the peer review.

Isn't a privilege needed to rollback a revision? Can anyone rollback any revision without limitation?

Comment: Which question?

Comment: Please don't perform tests on live questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that because it is Community Wiki.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/81947/revisions

They have lower limits (only need [100 reps](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit-community-wiki) to edit those)

Comment: As an aside, Roy: rolling back "a total of half the the questions" to "2 times more than" changes that post a lot. Why not just remove the erroneous words?